# how to identify json object or json array from a json parsing text?

Tags: json, parsing

i hav one problem , i parsed xml using json parsing and get json text. now i have to get values from xml. from that json text how i can identify jsonObject, jsonArray etc...

Comment: You parsed XML using JSON parsing? Why???

Comment: JSON and XML are different technologies. You need to parse each one as it is, not that way.

Comment: I'm bizarrely curious what the OP was actually trying to ask.  forever, it will remain mysterious...

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this with JavaScript in a browser, try [parsing the XML using jQuery](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/xml-parsing-with-jquery).